# How to add a converter to parameterized messages in JSF 1.2?

Tags: converters, jsf-1.2, parameterized, param, outputformat

I'm looking for a way to convert my params in a parameterized text inside a JSF 1.2 xhtml page.

Let's say I have this parameterized message in my `messages.properties` (please ignore the stupidity of this example):

```
EXAMPLE_TEXT=Right now {0} Euro is {1} US-Dollar.
```

And I would like the output to look like this:

```
Right now 1 Euro is 1.3658 US-Dollar.
```

Then my xhtml code looks like this:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{messages.EXAMPLE_TEXT}">
    <f:param value="#{backingBean.euroValue}" />
    <f:param value="#{backingBean.dollarValue}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

I already have implemented a converter (let's say its ID is `bigDecimalConverter`) that converts numeric values to the particular formats.

My question now is: (How) can a converter be registered to the output's param values?

I imagine something like this (which unfortunately seems to not be possible):

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{messages.EXAMPLE_TEXT}">
    <f:param value="#{backingBean.euroValue}" converter="bigDecimalConverter" />
    <f:param value="#{backingBean.dollarValue}" converter="bigDecimalConverter" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

Asking google I found [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/7201953), but it's no sufficient answer to my specific problem.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: What about design your output in other way `<h:outputText value="#{messages.TEXT1} #{backingBean.euroValue} #{messages.TEXT2} #{backingBean.dollarValue} #{messages.TEXT3}" \>`? Or 2nd way: create method in backing bean which return full String and call it in output text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Those are nice ways to circumvent this constraint and they seem to work just fine. I think I'm gonna go with one of them. I just thought, using a converter here was the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have exact the same output with `outputText`:

1) Change output to `<h:outputText value="#{messages.TEXT1} #{backingBean.euroValue} #{messages.TEXT2} #{backingBean.dollarValue} #{messages.TEXT3}" />`

2) Create method in backing bean which return full String and call it in output text.

(This answer was transformed from previous comment)